# How to open the same window second time - Swing

Tags: java, swing, window

I have few issues with my swing app which looks like this [app preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKzZ8.jpg)

This Frame is defined in Form class.
Form class is building in main class, code below

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Form form = new Form();

    checkIfRunning();
}
```

"New doctor" button has it's own listener which check is this object is already exist. Listener is defined in Form class.

```
newDoctorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private NDoctor dc = null;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (dc == null){
                dc = new NDoctor();}
            else dc.toFront();
        }
    });
```

Everything works fine, new window is opening as i want. [second window preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkn7p.jpg)
"Ok" button listener below

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            NDoctor.super.dispose();
        }
    });
```

When i close it i cant open it once more.

Im sure the problem is in  the main method. The "New Doctor"listener works but in run only once, when i close window it wont start until i call main method again, but this will create next Frame.

I hope you understand my problem. I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: `When i close it i cant open it once more.` Perhaps you wish to hide the window rather than `dispose` the window eg `setVisible(false);`

Comment: i think it wont solve my problem, but thanks ;)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)